# How do generate a negative supply for op amps ICs?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I know if you reverse + and - on a voltage supply you can measure a negative voltage using a multimeter, but for an op amp they only have one negative pin so I don’t think reversing + and - would work because you would be connecting the - voltage terminal to ground, I’m a little bit confused about how to achieve this, could you please explain how to get a - supply rail
Thanks, 
Be

Comment: Choose Ground to be the V+ of an isolated converter to get V- out.  Wherever you define 0V is "a local gnd".

Comment: you are incorrect with your statement about the multimeter. you measure a negative voltage when the multimeter positive probe is connected to a voltage that is more negative than the mutimeter negative probe. it is when you reverse the multimeter probes. ... the power supply voltages do not reverse.

Comment: Do you even need a negative supply? Many op-amps will work from a single supply depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: A negative supply needn't differ from a positive one.   It is just connected with its positive terminal to ground.

Answer (score 3):

Use a DC-DC converter, a charge pump capacitive inverter or an inverting buck converter. Some type of switching supply is the easiest approach if you only have a positive rail available and actually require a negative rail.

There are easily available DC-DC converters that will accept a single DC voltage input and produce (say) +/-15V rails that are galvanically isolated from the input.

It's easier for your meter because it has an inherently isolated supply in the form of the battery.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this thread helpful.

[Negative voltage from Arduino?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18173/negative-voltage-from-arduino/338287#338287)

I would suggest you to do it with two batteries as shown below. However, your question lacks detail, so I can't recommend what would be the best possible solution for you.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiaT06.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: A bit of diligence here would have been desirable. The TL081 will not work with a +-1V supply. Also, this is probably the most cumbersome possible solution.

Comment: Removed the 1V altogether. If by cumbersome you mean hard to implement I respectfully disagree.

Comment: By cumbersome I mean https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cumbersome "because of heaviness and bulk"

Answer (score 0):

If you are going oldschool you have to have two transformers or one with 3 output leads of which one is in the smack middle of secondary winding. Usually op amps require +/- 15 V DC. Now all you need is 7815 and 7915 ICs.

Comment: Hi koktelic, please include a [reference/attribution](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) for external content. I surmise it could be [this one?](http://powersupply33.com/15v-1a-regulated-symmetrical-power-supply.html/15v-1a-symmetrical-power-supply-circuit-schematic)

Comment: "Usually op amps require +/- 15 V DC" in days long gone by maybe, certainly not true any more.